# How to fetch Array value from hidden field in Servlet?

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page which contains a hidden field with array value.

```
<input value="[Ljava.lang.String;@9700b4" name="val0" type="hidden">
```

Now in java file which is servlet i want this array. So code like this,

```
String str[] = request.getParameterValues("val0");
```

But this one gives me array and my actual array is at 1st index of that array.
How can i get array values in my servlet page?

Comment: hey buddy, you want the details in jsp or jsp servlet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Ashish you can't directly access it.
Cast in array

```
<% String s[] = request.getAttribute("first_val");
if(s.length>0){
%>
<input value="<%=s[0]%>" name="first_val" type="hidden">
<% } 
else{
// As per your code
}
```

Hope work well

Answer (score 0):

`"[Ljava.lang.String;@9700b4"` isn't what you think it is; it's `toString()` on an array, not a proper serialization. What you're getting from `getParameterValues()` is *that exact* String, `"[Ljava.lang.String;@9700b4"` (probably not what you want). Normally, you'd either store that String[] on the session or you'd serialize it to, say, JSON, then deserialize `str[0]`.

Is there a delimiter you can use between those `Strings`? You probably want to see something like this in your HTML:

```
<input value="array_element_0,array_element_1,..." name="val0" type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly do like  that, You have to caste it first to the Array like:

```
 <% String str[] = request.getAttribute("val0"); // casting your String[] Object
// check if array contains value
if(str.length>0){
%>
<input value="<%=str[0]%>" name="val0" type="hidden">
<% } else{
// else part ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<% for (String s : jspStrArray) {%>
  <input value="<%=s%>" name="val0" type="hidden"/>
<%}%>
```

this will generate n hidden fields in ur jsp

Comment: i had assume that u want all the values in ur servlet from jsp

Answer (score 0):

your doing some mistake in your code, you should must add this sign `$` before value like following code is:

```
<form>
<c:forEach var="somename like users" items="${user}">
<input type="hidden" name="val0" value="${[Ljava.lang.String;@9700b4}">
</c:forEach>
</form>
```

*some name mean where did you get the details like users in servlet page and same like items user in jsp page.

Above code will generates HTML code like

```
<input type="hidden" name="val0" value="${[Ljava.lang.String;@9700b4}">
```

Access these values in servlet,

```
String str[]  = request.getParameterValues("va10");
for(String str[]  : va10)
{
  out.println("product values : "+str[]);
}
```